# GridView image with one column

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I don't know how to align my picture at the top of grid

there is my code of ImageAdaptater.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
File[] files;
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Favorite" + File.separator + "Pictures");
    files = dir.listFiles();

}
public int getCount() {
    return files.length;
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return files[position].getAbsolutePath();
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(files[position].getAbsolutePath()));
    return imageView;

}

}
```

And my layout:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/dinamicGrid"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
```

There is the result...

[image: Big white space before my picture]

Why is there a big white space before my ImageView how can I remove this white space ?

thanks

Comment: Why are you using a GridView if you only want one column?

Comment: @TheWanderer so what can I use ? it's not the problem :/ just I don't want this white space

Comment: It is the problem. That's not how GridViews work. If you need a single column list, use a RecyclerView.

Comment: I understand sorry @TheWanderer recyclerView or ListView ?